# docker-compose mongodb phoenix, [error] failed to connect: ** (Mongo.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hi I am getting this error when I try to run docker-compose up on my yml file.

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```js
version: '3.6'
services:
  phoenix:
    # tell docker-compose which Dockerfile it needs to build
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    # map the port of phoenix to the local dev port
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    # mount the code folder inside the running container for easy development
    volumes:
      - . .
    # make sure we start mongodb when we start this service
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```js
# base image elixer to start with
FROM elixir:1.6

# install hex package manager
RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix local.rebar --force

# install the latest phoenix 
RUN mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez --force

# create app folder
COPY . .
WORKDIR ./

# install dependencies
RUN mix deps.get

# run phoenix in *dev* mode on port 4000
CMD mix phx.server
```

Is this a problem with my dev.exs setup or something to do with the compatibility of docker and phoenix / docker and mongodb?

Comment: Is docker export ports 27017 work? Try `netstat -at | grep 27017`

Comment: tcp6       0      0  localhost.27017        *.*                    LISTEN
     
tcp4       0      0  *.27017                *.*                    LISTEN

What does this mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on explicitly says:

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> - depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready,

and advises you to implement the logic to wait for mongodb to spinup and be ready to accept connections by yourself: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

In your case it could be something like:

```
CMD wait-for-db.sh && mix phx.server
```

where `wait-for-db.sh` can be as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
until nc -z localhost 27017; do echo "waiting for db"; sleep 1; done
```

for which you need `nc` and `wait-for-db.sh` installed in the container.

There are plenty of other alternative tools to test if db container is listening on the target port.

---

**UPDATE:**

The network connection between containers is described at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/:

When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:

- A network called `myapp_default` is created, where `myapp` is name of the directory where `docker-compose.yml` is stored.
- A container is created using phoenix’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `phoenix`.
- A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `db`.

Each container can now look up the hostname `phoenix` or `db` and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, phoenix’s application code could connect to the URL `mongodb://db:27017` and start using the Mongodb database.

Comment: So I think this isn't the issue. I ran docker-compose up db first then docker-compose up phoenix. Phoenix app for some reason does not connect to localhost:27017

Comment: It shouldn't. localhost is local. Phoenix should connect to the mongo container. Something like `mongodb://db:27017` https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: ok if that's the case, i'm reading the documentation on docker hub, but i can't seem to find which uri to specify. https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: I have updated the answer with quotes from the docs, not sure I can put it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with my dev environment not connecting to the mongodb url specified in docker-compose. Instead of localhost, it should be db as named in my docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

For clarity to dev env:

- modify config/dev.exs to *(replace with correct vars)*

```
  username: System.get_env("PGUSER"),
  password: System.get_env("PGPASSWORD"),
  database: System.get_env("PGDATABASE"),
  hostname: System.get_env("PGHOST"),
  port:     System.get_env("PGPORT"),
```

- create a **dot env** file on the root folder of your project *(replace with relevant vars to the db service used)*

```
PGUSER=some_user
PGPASSWORD=some_password
PGDATABASE=some_database
PGPORT=5432
PGHOST=db
```

Note that we have added **port**.
Host can be *localhost* but should be *mongodb* or *db* or even *url* when working on a docker-compose or server or k8s.

---

will update answer for prod config...